# cannot run flutter code in emulator in VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, dart

how to sovle this error. working with flutter in vscode.

```
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have a look at this topic https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59975#issue-642943893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime it don't work if your Internet Connection is slow.

Do this. It will help you. change gradle version if new update is available.

I was finally able to solve the problem. The problem is with the gradle and low internet bandwidth.
Just delete the C:\Users\USERNAME.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all
and download it manually from [https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip] or delete the old gradle files and let them download manually by using flutter run Be sure to check your gradle version before proceeding.